# mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result geolocation

Tags: php, mysqli

I really don't know what i'm doing wrong. I want to count the rows in my query. My id's started from 1 to ... step 1, so the biggest number is the last record. I only want to let the script run on the last record of de DB. So here is my code.

```
public function saveLongLan()
    {
        define("MAPS_HOST", "maps.google.com");
        define("KEY", "MYKEY");

        $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
        if (!$link) {
         die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
        }

        // Set the active MySQL database
        $db_selected = mysql_select_db('Foodsquare', $link);
        if (!$db_selected)  
        {
            die("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
        }

        $query = "SELECT * FROM tblPlaces WHERE 1";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);


            if (!$result) 
                {
                    die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
                }


        $delay = 0;
        $base_url = "http://" . MAPS_HOST . "/maps/geo?output=xml" . "&key=" . KEY;

        while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
            {
                $geocode_pending = true;

                    while ($geocode_pending) 
                        {
                            $address = $row["Street"];
                            $id = $row["Id"];
                            $request_url = $base_url . "&q=" . urlencode($address);
                            $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");

                            $status = $xml->Response->Status->code;
                            if (strcmp($status, "200") == 0) 
                                {
                                      // Successful geocode
                                      $geocode_pending = false;
                                      $coordinates = $xml->Response->Placemark->Point->coordinates;
                                      //explode functie breekt een string af vanaf een bepaald teken en stopt hem dan in een array
                                      $coordinatesSplit = explode(',', $coordinates);
                                      // formaat: Longitude, Latitude, Altitude
                                      $lat = $coordinatesSplit[1];//getal = plaats in array
                                      $lng = $coordinatesSplit[0];


                                      $query = sprintf("UPDATE tblPlaces " .
                                                " SET lat = '%s', lng = '%s' " .
                                                " WHERE id = '". $row_cnt . "' LIMIT 1;",
                                             mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
                                             mysql_real_escape_string($lng),
                                             mysql_real_escape_string($id));
                                      $update_result = mysql_query($query);
                                          if (!$update_result) 
                                            {
                                            die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
                                            }
                                } else if (strcmp($status, "620") == 0) 
                                    {
                                          // sent geocodes too fast
                                          $delay += 100000;
                                    } 
                                    else 
                                    {
                                        // failure to geocode
                                        $geocode_pending = false;
                                        echo "Address " . $address . " failed to geocoded. ";
                                    echo "Received status " . $status . " \n";
                                    }
                                usleep($delay);
                        }
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your query is incorrect `$query = "SELECT * FROM tblPlaces WHERE 1"`;

you should specify the column name after where clause for comparison with a value for example: `WHERE column_name = 1` or something like that.

Comment: I don't think so, the query i running very well without the rowcount, its copy past from google api.  thanks

Comment: I have faced similar problems with my queries just because I forgot to mention the where clause conditions. Go to this site for a tutorial on where clause : [where clause tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm)

Answer (score -1):

You're using mysqli_num_rows($result) but you aren't using MySQLi.

Change:

```
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

To:

```
$row_cnt = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

And you should be good to go.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @vascowhite Sorry man, i'm trying to convert this to mysqli at this moment